# Php refresh page without lossing the table view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

What should I do in order to not loss the table view every time I update the data below of my table.

Please help me for our project.

Where should I put the script in my code? Here is my code

this is my `firstpage.php`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<td colspan="8" style="text-align:center;">';
  echo '<a rel="facebox" href="editperq.php?access_code='.$code.'&pe='.$row['fld_qper'].'">'.$row['fld_qper'].'</a>';
  echo "%";
  echo '</td>';
}
```

this is my `editperq.php`

```
<form action="editperqexec.php" method="post">
<input name="access_code" type="hidden" class="ed" id="brnu" value="<?php echo $_GET['access_code']; ?>" />
Percentage <br />
<input name="percentage" required="" autofocus type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" value="<?php echo $_GET['pe']; ?>" />
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="save" id="button1" />
</form>
```

and this is my ediperqexec.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());

$access_code=$_POST['access_code'];
$percentage=$_POST['percentage'];

mysql_query("UPDATE tblpercentage SET fld_qper='$percentage' WHERE access_code='$access_code'");
header('location: firstpage.php');
?>
```

As you can see the `header('location: firstpage.php')` every time I want to update my records below of my table it always goes back at top of my table view.

[this is my table preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJEXS.png)

Comment: You will need to use ajax

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: I have given you the idea that how to achieve your desired goal. I just cant write the whole code for you. Looking like you are already using facebox so I would suggest to check the developer console for any JS errors.

Comment: help me please I have no idea for this code